# Hibernate Search + Spring + JPA + 2 webapps - correct configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I have search long and hard, and cannot find a definitive answer.

I have 2 webapps running on a single instance of tomcat: `/server` and `/ROOT`

I have configured Hibernate Search configured for one of my entities, ie `Products`.

These entities are edited/added on `/server` and searched for by front end users on the website `/ROOT`

during normal operations, everything works as it should, editing entities on the server will result in those changes reflecting when doing a search on the front end.

however, after an undetermined time, or sequence of events, the index no longer gets updated.

here is the configuration for `/server`

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}" />
</util:map>
```

and here is the config for `/ROOT`

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}" />
</util:map>
```

Essentially identical.

and here is how my Entity is configured, via an AspectJ ITD

```
privileged aspect Product_Search {

declare @type: Product: @Indexed;

declare @method :public Long Product.getId() : @DocumentId;
declare @method :public String Product.getTitle() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getSubTitle() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getAlternativeTitle() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getIdentifier() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getPrimaryCreators() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getSecondaryCreators() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getSubjectArea() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getPublisher() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO);
declare @method :public String Product.getTags() : @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO);
```

Upon further searching, I discovered the master/slave DirectoryProvider

`/server`

```
    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem-master" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}/primary" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.sourceBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}/master" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.refresh" value="120" />
</util:map>
```

`/ROOT`

```
    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem-slave" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.sourceBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}/master" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${lucene.index.folder}/slave" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.refresh" value="300" />
</util:map>
```

This seemed to work, until earlier to day, when for some reason, my index "reset" itself, and only contained the items that were part of the last product import.
What I mean is, that my DB has 10000 items, but if I did a `query = new MatchAllDocsQuery();`, I only got 15 (the size of the last import)

This is really driving me crazy.

At the moment, I am having to bring down the websites, delete the index, start the server, reindex using `FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager());
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();`

Let me know if you need any more info

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If changes are only coming in via the *server* app and you always want to run *server* and *ROOT* on the same machine, there is no need for a master/slave setup. A simple filesystem setup should do, however, you want to make sure that on the *ROOT* app _hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual_ is specified. This way index updates would only occur when the explicit indexing API is used on the *ROOT* app.

have you turned on logging? Is there anything in the logs. I think the first step is trying to reproduce the problem in a reliable way. If you just say it works initially, but then suddenly it starts failing, it makes it hard to find the cause. Have you tried with some automated load tests?

Comment: Just happened again in production. Going to turn the hibernate search log level to DEBUG for the next couple of days.

Comment: If there is a 90% possibility in the near future, that we are going to also be editing in the _ROOT_ app, then is a master/slave setup recommended? Does master/slave have to be run with JMS?

Comment: As long as the two apps are on the same machine you can use the file system directory. Lucene has its own index locking mechanism so the index cannot be corrupted (that's what this exclusive flag is about in the other answer). Master/Slave is required once you have multiple machines. You could also use JGroups for the etup, but JMS is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

One idea - maybe you should switch to [non-exclusive mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#lucene-indexing-performance) (see for `exclusive_index_use`)