# Spring, JPA, Hibernate Search integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a Spring project where I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search. The project works fine other than the part that involves Hibernate Search creating the indexes.

From what I understand from the docs, the index directory is supposed to be created at application startup. No index directory is being created and no errors are showing in the logs. I've even tried to create the directory manually before starting the app, but nothing is ever being written to it, even when new entities are being saved to the database.

I've seen numerous posts on the Spring and Hibernate forums asking how to do this same thing, but all of them are unanswered or the OP has just stated, "I've figured it out" and given no solution.

Also, based on these posts, such as this one: [Hibernate Search + Spring + JPA + 2 webapps - correct configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479622/hibernate-search-spring-jpa-2-webapps-correct-configuration), I'm lead to believe that I don't need to define a separate persistence.xml if I'm using Spring/JPA to manage my entities, but I'm still a bit unclear on this.

Below are the relevant portions of my application context and my entity. What am I missing?

Application context:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${db.generateDdl}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${db.showSql}" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect.class}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
    <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="C:\Users\Luke\indexes" />
</util:map>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${db.connection.url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver.class}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

Entity:

```
...
@Entity
@Indexed(index = "myentity")
@Table(name = "entity_table")
public class MyEntity implements BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6320371154137986977L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "my_string")
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED,
        store = Store.YES)
    private String myString;
...
```

Boot Log:

```
Running Jetty 6.1.26
2013-04-30 09:36:32.317:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
ParentLoaderPriority enabled
Context path:/myapp
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\workspace-java\myapp\target\classes
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\scribe\scribe\1.3.3\scribe-1.3.3.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.1.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\java-persistence\jpa-api\2.0-cr-1\jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.3.0.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.5.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.7.1\aspectjrt-1.7.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.1\slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.1\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.3.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.0.CR2\jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.1.9.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.17.1-GA\javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.1.9.Final\hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-search\3.4.1.Final\hibernate-search-3.4.1.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-search-analyzers\3.4.1.Final\hibernate-search-analyzers-3.4.1.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers\3.1.0\lucene-analyzers-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\solr\solr-analysis-extras\3.1.0\solr-analysis-extras-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\solr\solr-core\3.1.0\solr-core-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\solr\solr-solrj\3.1.0\solr-solrj-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-highlighter\3.1.0\lucene-highlighter-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-memory\3.1.0\lucene-memory-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-misc\3.1.0\lucene-misc-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial\3.1.0\lucene-spatial-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spellchecker\3.1.0\lucene-spellchecker-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\solr\solr-commons-csv\3.1.0\solr-commons-csv-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-smartcn\3.1.0\lucene-smartcn-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-stempel\3.1.0\lucene-stempel-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\3.1.0\lucene-core-3.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.22\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\log4j-1.2.14.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\jstl\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-core\3.0.1\tiles-core-3.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\2.0\commons-digester-2.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-api\3.0.1\tiles-api-3.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-request-api\1.0.1\tiles-request-api-1.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-jsp\3.0.1\tiles-jsp-3.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-servlet\3.0.1\tiles-servlet-3.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-request-servlet\1.0.1\tiles-request-servlet-1.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-template\3.0.1\tiles-template-3.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-autotag-core-runtime\1.1.0\tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-request-jsp\1.0.1\tiles-request-jsp-1.0.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.2.3\httpclient-4.2.3.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.2.2\httpcore-4.2.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-core\2.5.0\querydsl-core-2.5.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.2\guava-11.0.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\commons\mysema-commons-lang\0.2.2\mysema-commons-lang-0.2.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.2\jsr305-1.3.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\2.2\cglib-2.2.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-jpa\2.5.0\querydsl-jpa-2.5.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-apt\2.5.0\querydsl-apt-2.5.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-codegen\2.5.0\querydsl-codegen-2.5.0.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\com\mysema\codegen\codegen\0.4.11\codegen-0.4.11.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.9.5\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Users\Luke\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Program Files\eclipse-java\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar
ProjectClassLoader: entry=C:\Program Files\eclipse-java\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
Excluded entry=C:\workspace-java\myapp\target\test-classes 
init scanning folders...
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\target\classes
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\tiles-config.xml
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\application-context.xml
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\security-context.xml
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\application-context-base.xml
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
add to scan list:C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
Starting scanner at interval of 5 seconds.
2013-04-30 09:36:32.473:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2013-04-30 09:36:32.934:INFO:/myapp:Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp]
2013-04-30 09:36:32.980:INFO:/myapp:Initializing log4j from [C:\workspace-java\myapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
2013-04-30 09:36:33.033:INFO:/myapp:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-04-30 09:36:36.566:INFO:/myapp:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
2013-04-30 09:36:36.657:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: Do you see any Hibernate Search related log output. Can you post the boot log output? Have you tried with persistence.xml? Also have you tried defining the properties as map as seen in the question you are referencing? Which versions if Hibernate and Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: @Hardy Thanks for the response. Posted boot log. Using property map - same result (had tried this before). I don't see any log output from Hibernate Search. I'm using Hibernate Search version 3.4.1, and version 4.1.9 of Hibernate Core. Haven't tried with persistence.xml because I don't want to use it if I don't have to. As I said, I'm a little unclear on when this is necessary. My understanding (which could be wrong) is that it's not required if you are using Spring/JPA w/annotation based configuration; however, I'm unclear as to whether it's required for Hibernate Search specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it was an incompatibility between the versions of Hibernate Core and Hibernate Search.

Changed my pom file to pull in Hibernate Search version 4.1.1 with Hibernate Core version 4.1.9 and it works fine now. Only other thing I had to change was the `index` attribute on my field annotations due to `Index.TOKENIZED` no longer being supported. Now it's: `@Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES)`.

Big thanks to @Hardy for prompting me for version numbers and helping me figure out that this was the issue.